# Creating a type for an object that includes a Map plus other keys in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a data structure like this:

```
{
  anyKey: {
    id: 'blah',
    val: 12  
  },
  anotherKey: {
    id: 'blah2',
    val: 13  
  },
  data: 'fred',
  count: 15  
}
```

I want to create a Type (or Interface) for the data structure. I've tried to use Record, but it doesn't work when I do this:

```
type IdVal {
  id: string;
  val: number;
}

type MyType = {
  Record<string, IdVal>;
  data: string;
  count: number
}
```

What should I be doing here? Is the fact that I want to accept any key other than `data` or `count` making it impossible to turn into a Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to solve this, and is perhaps a better design anyway, is to change the data structure to be more like this:

```
{
  map: {
    anyKey: {
      id: 'blah',
      val: 12
    },
    anotherKey: {
      id: 'blah2',
      val: 13
    }
  },
  data: 'fred',
  count: 15
}
```

And have a type of this:

```
type IdVal {
  id: string;
  val: number;
}

type MyType = {
  map: Record<string, IdVal>;
  data: string;
  count: number
}
```